# Find common functionalities or functions between 2 programs

Tags: architecture, optimization

I've been facing a problem recently, in which I want to optimize two programs.

For that, I wanted to create some kind of "Common Interface" which I could reuse between my two programs.

However, the code of these are approximately 1000 lines, and I don't want to spend a big amount of time checking if this or that function is the same as this one and whatsoever.

So I used BOUML to check the similarities between class diagrams. But I wonder if there is a global way to do such a study ?

Comment: I might be misinterpreting your question somewhat but if you're using Visual Studio 2012 perhaps the 'Find Clones' feature might help. I'll not go into a great amount of detail here in case you're not using Visual Studio or even working in the Microsoft stack. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205279.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both programs are from the same author, and you have the suspicion that the author might have copy-pasted some functions from one program to the other, using a tool like "diff" (or WinDiff or WinMerge) may help you to find some of that code blocks. Of course, this works only if you do not have too many source code files (which I guess is unlikely, since 1000 lines of code is not really huge).

However, if you want to find functions or code blocks which do essentially the same, but the functions in stake have a completely different implementation, there is IMHO no short-cut to learn and understand what the code does (at least the parts you want to merge). Before refactoring common functionality, you have to be sure that the code you want to refactor really does the same. You may not have to understand the full code, but even for identifying candidates, a rough understanding of the functions is IMHO necessary.

Comment: In addition to Diff tools, a code duplication detection tool would also work well with this strategy.

Comment: @Brian: of course, I found this SO post asking exactly for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546487/tools-to-identify-code-duplications

Answer (score 1):

Well, I assume that you know the functionality of both programs. Extracting the common interface is a regular refactoring job since you probably just want to remove code duplication.

So just load your two programs in any IDE and look at the outline view where the classes/method signatures are shown. Since you know the functionality of both programs it shouldn't be a difficult task to find the duplicate code parts.

Comment: What if I don't know all the functionality of both programs ?

Comment: @Xaltar What do you know about the programs at all?

Comment: To be simple, I know waht they do. I've seen on class diagrams how they are structured and what are the "groups" of fonction and I can deduce what are they role. I've discovered these programs not so long ago and I haven't programmed them myself.